# Issue with cache

Tags: html, caching, nginx

I use last version of Chrome and I have allow all possible caching.

I have a static web server with a simple `.html` page. I see that Chrome successfully cache my page html.

But now set something like that on my nginx virtual host to disable cache

```
location ~* ^.+\.(html|htm)$ {
            expires -1;
}
```

Now, is it possible that browser client can cache my html??

So, more generally, the server manages the possibility of cache?
So I'm sure that nobody can cache this page?